# Find the equation of the Parabola Projectile Motion

Tags: calculus, conic-sections, projectile-motion

I'm not really sure how to do this Projectile Motion question since it gives no equations of motion or anything, just a lot of text and conditions:

A tall building stands on level ground. The nozzle of a water sprinkler is positioned at a point $P$ on the ground at a distance $d$ from a wall of the building. Water sprays from the nozzle with speed $V$ and the nozzle can be pointed in any direction from $P$.

Suppose that $V=\sqrt{2gd}$.
Show that the portion of the wall that can be sprayed with water is a parabolic segment of height ${8\over 15}d$ and area ${5\over 2}d^2\sqrt{15}$.

Someone has already asked this question, but they solved it before anyone else could answer it, so I was wondering if anyone else would be able to assist me? I tried to solve this question by setting the angle in the vertical plane to a constant $\frac{\pi}{4}$ for max range, and varied the angle of the diagonal in which the trajectory of the projectile would lie in. I ended up getting a result:

$y=\sqrt{x^2+d^2} - {x^2\over 4d}$

I'm certain this isn't a parabola though so I wasn't sure what I did wrong. Could someone point out the flaw in this argument? For reference, the equation of the parabola is, I believe:

$y=-{x^2\over 8d} + {15\over 8}d$

Thanks!

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: I fixed it. Could you unhold this post now, please?

Comment: You're unlikely to have it reopened since it lacks any evidence that you've tries the problem yourself nor have you given any context so that we can answer at a level suitable for you. I suggest that you edit the question accordingly. Don't be deterred though: I'll upvote it once it's done that way.

Comment: Is it okay now?

Comment: You shouldn’t be looking for maximum *range*, but maximum *height* at a given distance.

Comment: Use the chat room C.R.U.D.E on this site. They'll help you reopen the question.

Comment: How do I access that?

Comment: Click [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=math.stackexchange.com) at the bottom of the page. I see that your question has been opened now though . . .

Comment: Max height should be $\frac {15}8d$, not $\frac 8{15}d$. Angle of $\frac {\pi}4$ gives maximum height of trajectory but not maximum height at a given distance, in this case the height when the projectile hits the wall.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a typo in the problem :  The $V = 2\sqrt{gd}$ and then the rest follows as given below in the solution.  I think I got what the book answer is.

Solution as follows:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Yes, looks like it should be $V=2\sqrt{gd}$.

Comment: I wasted a lot of time on the OP's incorrect expression.  That is OK, I have become a master now trying to figure out how it could work.

Answer (score 1):

$\hspace{4.5cm}$[image]

General projectile trajectory equation:
$$y=u\tan\alpha-\frac {gu^2}{2V^2}\sec^2\alpha$$
At $u=\ell$, 
$$\begin{align}
y&=\ell \tan\alpha-\frac {g\ell^2}{2V^2}\sec^2\alpha\\
\frac{\text dy}{\text d\alpha}&=\ell\sec^2\alpha-\frac {g\ell^2}{2V^2}\cdot 2\sec\alpha\cdot \sec\alpha\tan\alpha\\
&=\ell\sec^2\alpha\left(1-\frac {g\ell^2}{V^2}\tan\alpha\right)
=0\;\text{when}\; \tan\alpha=\frac {V^2}{g\ell}\\
\therefore y_\text{max}=h&=\ell\left(\frac {V^2}{g\ell}\right)-\frac {g\ell^2}{2V^2}\left(1+\frac {V^4}{g^2\ell^2}\right)\\
&=\frac {V^2}{2g}-\frac {g\ell^2}{2V^2}\end{align}$$
For a given lateral displacement $x$,    $\ell^2=d^2+x^2$
$$\therefore h=\frac {V^2}{2g}-\frac g{2V^2}(d^2+x^2)$$
Given $V=2\sqrt{gd}$ i.e. $V^2=4gd$, hence
$$h=2d-\frac 1{8d}(d^2+x^2)\\
=\color{red}{\frac {15}8 d-\frac {x^2}{8d}}$$

From the equation, when $x=0$, the height at the centre, i.e. maximum height  is given by $$\color{red}{h=\frac {15}8d}$$.
Area under the curve is given by

Also, when $y=0$, $x=\pm d\sqrt{15}$. As the curve is symmetrical, the area under the curve is given by
$$\begin{align}
2 \int_0^{d\sqrt{15}}\left(\frac {15}8d-\frac {x^2}{8d} \; \right)\text dx
&=2\cdot \frac 18 \left[15d\cdot x-\frac {x^3}{3d}\right]_0^{d\sqrt{15}}\\
&=\color{red}{\frac 52d^2\sqrt{15}}
\end{align}$$

---

It is interesting to note that $$\alpha=\arctan\left(\frac {4d}{\sqrt{d^2+x^2}}\right)$$
i.e. $\alpha$ decreases slowly with increasing $x$, meaning that as the projectile  moves away from the centre (plane perpendicular to wall) the angle of launch must be decreased slightly to achieve maximum height on hitting the wall.

---

NB: here we use $y$ for general height of projectile and $h$ for maximum height when it hits the wall.

---

**ADDENDUM - Another Method**

Using a cylindrical coordinate system $(r,\theta, y)$ with radius $r$, angle $\theta$ and vertical distance $y$, the equation for general family of trajectories launched from the origin (i.e. $P$) in direction $\theta$ and at angle $\alpha$ from the plane $y=0$ is given by
$$\begin{align}
y
&=r\tan\alpha-\frac {gr^2}{2V^2}\sec^2\alpha\\
&=r\left(\tan\alpha-\frac r{8d}\sec^2\alpha\right)&&(V=2\sqrt{gd})\tag{1}
\end{align}$$

The plane of the wall is given by
$$r=\frac d{\sin\theta}\tag{2}$$
Putting $(2)$ in $(1)$ gives
$$\begin{align}
y
&=\frac d{\sin\theta}\left(\tan\alpha-\frac {\sec^2\alpha}{8\sin\theta}\right)\\
\frac {\text dy}{\text d\alpha}
&=\frac {d\cdot \sec^2\alpha}{\sin\theta}\left(1-\frac {\tan\alpha}{4\sin\theta}\right)\\
&=0\;\text{when}\; \tan\alpha=4\sin\theta\\
\therefore y^*
&=\frac d{\sin\theta}\left(4\sin\theta-\frac {1+16\sin^2\theta}{8\sin\theta}\right)\\
&=d\left(2-\frac 1{8\sin^2\theta}\right)\\
&=2\left(2-\frac {d^2+x^2}{8d^2}\right)\\
&=\color{red}{\frac {15d}8-\frac {x^2}{8d}}
\end{align}$$